# Wpf Richtextbox selection starting column and row number returns different values

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing, richtextbox

I am initializing my Richtextbox,

```
void InitRTBFlowDocument()
    {
        Style noSpaceStyle = new Style(typeof(Paragraph));
        noSpaceStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Paragraph.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
        rtbTextEditor.Resources.Add(typeof(Paragraph), noSpaceStyle);
    }
```

I want to get Richtext box selection words row and column numbers. I wrote the code as follows, First time it is returning correctly.

```
void rtbTextEditor_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the richtext box selected text
        Init.RTBSelectionText = rtbTextEditor.Selection.Text.Trim();
        Init.SelectionText = rtbTextEditor.Selection.Text.Trim();
        Init.isSelect = true;
        if (Init.RTBSelectionText != string.Empty)
        {
            TextPointer tp = rtbTextEditor.Selection.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(-2, LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (tp != null)
                GetStartingIndex();
        } 
        Init.RTBContent = new TextRange(rtbTextEditor.Document.ContentStart, rtbTextEditor.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    }

void GetStartingIndex()
    {
        TextPointer tp1 = rtbTextEditor.Selection.Start.GetLineStartPosition(0);
        TextPointer tp2 = rtbTextEditor.Selection.Start;

        int SelectionColumnIndex = tp1.GetOffsetToPosition(tp2)-1;//column number

        int someBigNumber = int.MaxValue;
        int lineMoved;
        rtbTextEditor.Selection.Start.GetLineStartPosition(-someBigNumber, out lineMoved); //Line number
        int SelectionRowIndex = -lineMoved;

        Init.RTBTextPoint = new RTBTextPointer();
        Init.RTBTextPoint.Row = SelectionRowIndex;
        Init.RTBTextPoint.Column = SelectionColumnIndex;
     }
```

After clearing and added new content, The position returns wrong number,

```
 public void DisplayContent(string content)
    {
        //Clear the rich text box
        rtbTextEditor.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        rtbTextEditor.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(content)));
    }
```

Is anything rong in the above code.
Please help me
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the contents in the RTB does not only contain text, it contains these things called TextPointerContext's. TextPointer's take this into account. You can check what the TextPointer is adjacent to by using:

```
TextPointer.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection);
```

To get the next TextPointer:

```
TextPointer.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection);
```

Some sample code I used in a recent project, this makes sure that the pointer context is of type Text:

```
while (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) 
                             != TextPointerContext.Text)
{
    start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    if (start == null) return;
}
```

When you clear your RTB, you're probably removing some of these pointer contexts. So be careful when using GetPositionAtOffset(). This should give you a "pointer" in the right direction. If you need any more help me know.

Good hunting!

Comment: Thanks JessMcintosh! how to change the richtextbox content without remove TextPointerContext.. please help me

Comment: Instead of not trying to remove the TextPointerContexts, check to see if there are any and account for them.

Comment: I am just clearing the RTB content.. I am not removing any TextPointerContexts directly..

Comment: could you please explain me